# Excel VBA: Case query

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code, which sorts an input number into a convenient range:

```
Public Sub TestCase2()

Dim Number As Long
Dim Message As String

Number = InputBox("Enter a number:", "Number entry")
Message = "Number is "

Select Case Number
Case Is < -10
    MsgBox (Message & "less than -10")
Case Is < 0
    MsgBox (Message & "equal to or greater than -10 but less than zero")
Case Is = 0
    MsgBox (Message & "equal to zero")
Case Is < 10
    MsgBox (Message & "greater than zero but less than 10")
Case Else
    MsgBox (Message & "greater than or equal to 10")
End Select

End Sub
```

It falls over when I enter -10.5 - I would have thought it would output:
`Number is less than -10`
But it says:
`Number is equal to or greater than -10 but less than zero.`

If I enter -10.6, the output is as expected: `Number is less than -10.`

Also, it falls over with an entry of 0.001: it says `Number is equal to zero.` Which it isn't.

I cannot work with integers here - the input has to have decimals (up to 3).

Is there a neater way of doing this? Many thanks for your constructive input.

Regards,
Shane (VBA newbie of 4 weeks).

PS I know I can do this with If-Then statements, but I'm just getting to grips with Select Case-Case Else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[InpuBox function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) returns string. So, to be able to compare value returned by this function, you need to convert it into proper numeric format:

```
Dim sNumber As String
sNumber = InputBox(...)

'prevent Cancel click
If sNmber = "" Then Exit Sub

'prevent non-numeric value
If Not IsNumeric(sNmber) Then Exit Sub

Select Case CDbl(sNumber)
....
```

If you want to use `If .. else` statement instead of `Select case` , please see: [If .. Then ... Else ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Maciej. This works perfectly.  I had not realised that MsgBox always produces a string output.
Regards,
Shane.

Comment: @ShaneMHewitt, you're very welcome ;) Cheers, Maciej

Answer (score 0):

Number may have to be dimmed as Single or Double

```
   Dim Number As Single
```